# Clearing localstack s3 bucket

Tags: localstack

How do I clear all objects in an s3 bucket in [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) via the **REST api**?

So `aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 rm s3://localbucket --recursive` but via REST.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question about localstack, you have to use the S3 API to do that.

1. Your own suggestion `aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 rm s3://localbucket --recursive` is itself using REST under the covers, but I guess you mean in application code
2. Use any of the supported SDKs from AWS, e.g. Java, Python, JS: https://aws.amazon.com/tools/
   e.g. v1 Java SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#delete-objects
3. If you want to do the HTTP call yourself it gets a little trickier. You can start here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_control_DeleteBucket.html, but first you need to delete all objects in the bucket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html